# Show a website inside tab layout an ionic2 + typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am working on an ionic framework-v2 based mobile application. My application is a tab based application. In the last tab I want to load an external website, but I 'm not able to implement it.
I Want something like below..

[image: I want something like this]

I'm used tabs in it. and change in the config file for move tabs in top . but not figure it out how to display my website in the tabs.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried yet?

Comment: @AksharPatel : I tried IFrame.  It is working in android. But on Ios Based device it freeze the scroll.                                                                                          i used like  `<ion-content class="contact-us-view" overflow-scroll="true">
    <iframe class="iframe_test" src="http://stackoverflow.com/"></iframe>
</ion-content>`

Answer (score 0):

this is how I load a Ifream in my app. Give it a try

```
<iframe id="iframe" ng-src="{{url}}" style="overflow:auto;border:0px;width:100%;min-height:100vh">
        </iframe>
```