# Checkbox Alert Controller - Add 3 Buttons

Tags: css, typescript, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I make one application with IONIC-2 Beta version. i 'm use Checkbox Alert Controller, and add two buttons "Okay" And "Cancel", Now i need to add one more button in Alert Controller. i implement below to add one more button.

```
alert.addButton('Cancel');
 alert.addButton({
   text: 'Info',
   role: 'info',
   handler: data => {
     //this.nav.push(DoubleMatPage,{"form_data":this.form_data,"offset":data});
   }
 });
 alert.addButton({
   text: 'Okay',
   handler: data => {
     this.nav.push(DoubleMatPage,{"form_data":this.form_data,"offset":data});
   }
 });
```

It's work good but it will align vertically like below,

[image: It look like]

But, i want to align it in horizontally.

If anyone knows the solution, please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a few css rules to achieve that.

Since the buttons are being aligned by using flexbox, we can overwrite some of those css rules to be able to include three buttons in the modal instead of two. First, please notice that I added a custom css class (`custom-alert`) to the alert, so our css rules will affect this alert **only**:

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      cssClass: 'custom-alert',
      ...
});
```

And then:

```
.custom-alert button.alert-button-group {
    width: 33.33%;
}

.custom-alert .alert-button-group .button-inner {
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.custom-alert .alert-button-group-vertical {
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row ;
}
```

The magic is being done by setting the `width` to 33.33% to allow the buttons to fit in the same row, and then adding `flex-direction: row` to the container instead of the *column* value per default (that's why in your screenshot the buttons are in a column display).

Comment: yes It's work fine. my code works fine. now. Thank you so much. You are Genius.:)

Comment: Glad I could help! The guys at Ionic are the geniuses, I'm just enjoying  what they built :)

Comment: Yup thanks bro.  will you please help me in [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097557/show-a-website-inside-tab-layout-an-ionic2-typescript)

Comment: Sure, let me take a look and run some tests

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at the below code

```
presentConfirm() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Confirm purchase',
    message: 'Do you want to buy this book?',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Buy',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Buy clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'get',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Buy clicked');
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

> To get a button in horizontal we need all the button inside a single 
>   array
>
> But in your case you have 3 different array.

For more information about AlerControll check this [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/alert/AlertController/)

Comment: First of all thanks for replying my question. but still getting this problem. I want it in horizontal. if i use 2 button it is working fine but in more than 2 button then it will not displaying as i want.

Comment: I implement this  `  let alert = Alert.create({buttons: [
     {
       text: 'Cancel',
       role: 'cancel',
       handler: () => {
         console.log('Cancel clicked');
       }
     },
     {
       text: 'Buy',
       handler: () => {
         console.log('Buy clicked');
       }
     },
     {
       text: 'Info',
       handler: () => {
         console.log('Buy clicked');
       }
     }
   ]});`

Comment: this is issue happens because of space issue I highly recommend you not to use more then 2 buttons

Comment: in my project it is required. do you have any other alternative?

Comment: Try using grid use  `ion-row` and `ion-col` and decrease the size of the button that should to the trick

Comment: but i am not sure weather we can achive this in alert

Comment: No Men, It still not working.!! Watch the below answer. it is quite good. and working fine. [Watch This](https://plnkr.co/edit/TswcDp?p=preview).  But thanks for the reply buddy. :)

Comment: of course my answer is also similar to your answer but i have not included my third object any way thanks for the demo

Comment: right buddy. no worry thanks for reply. u also got +1 from my side. and pls please help me if possible in [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097557/show-a-website-inside-tab-layout-an-ionic2-typescript)